# Taking screenshot of higher resolution than actual display resolution

Tags: display, screen, display-resolution, screenshot

My computer has 1366x768 display. If I use <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>, then taken  picture will have 1366x768 resolution.
But there is a question: **Is it possible to get 1920x1080 picture with my 1366x768 display?**

One potential idea I thought is to make 4 virtual desktops like this:

[image: MultiDesktops]

But, I do not have an idea how to do this. Any help will be much appreciated.

**Edit:** Creating *Virtual Machine* with higher resolution is possible (thanks to @danzel), however I am looking for utilizing more native way using only the Host OS.

**Update 1:** The output of `xrandr --listmonitors`:

```
Monitors: 1
0: +*LVDS-1 1366/344x768/194+0+0  LVDS-1

$ sudo xrandr --addmode LVDS-1 1920x1080
xrandr: cannot find mode "1920x1080"
```

**Update 2:** Thanks to comment of user @Eate the question was solved by adding the custom resolution:

```
$ cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
$ sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
$ sudo xrandr --addmode LVDS-1 1920x1080_60.00
```

Then go to Display Settings and select 1920x1080.

Comment: Do you want an image on one window (larger than your real screen)? Do you have a setup with multiple desktops where a window can be larger than a screen?

Comment: @Volker Siegel, yes. Actually, I  want to take the screenshot of Firefox's window. But, I did not have a setup with multiple desktops...

Comment: @Olimjon the question is a bit unclear. Do you want to make a screenshot of a window that has 1920x1080 pixels, or do you want to make a screenshot of a 1366x768 pixel window and resize it to 1920x1080 pixels? BTW it is perfectly possible to run a virtual machine in a higher resolution than the  screens attached to the host.

Comment: @danzel, Well, imagine that there is a display with 1920x1080. In this display I press the button <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> and a 1920x1080 picture appears in the clipboard. So, I want to achieve this result with the lower resolution without any resizing. And in my desktop any window cannot have the pixels beyond 1366x768, so I should find a way out.

Comment: @danzel, Regarding to your BTW section. Yeah, I was wrong. I will edit the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Step 1

Try changing the resolution in Settings first. Go into Settings, and, depending on what version you're on, work your way into Displays. For 18.04, this is under Devices/Displays. Change screen resolution to  the resolution you want, for example 1920×1080. Take a screenshot with that new resolution, and then change it back when you're done.

### Step 2

If the resolution you need is not available, use this command to calculate the CVT mode lines for the resolution you want:

```
cvt 1920 1080
```

This example is for 1920×1080. It should output something like this:

```
1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Copy all of the text after `Modeline` (here, it is `"1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync`) and remember to include the quotation marks in the beginning. To add the new mode so you can use it, run this command:

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Use your modeline output in place of mine. Then, to add that new mode to your display so you can use it, you will need to know what the name of your monitor. To do that, run this:

```
xrandr
```

This will output a few lines. On the second line, you should see something like this:

```
(monitor_name) connected primary ...
```

That monitor name is your monitor's device name. To add the new resolution you added to your monitor, run this command:

```
sudo xrandr --addmode (monitor_name) "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Again, substitute in the monitor name you get from the previous step and the stuff after that from the `cvt` command. You have added the new resolution. Now, go back and try step 1.

Comment: OK, my display does not support 1920x1080. For me, the highest display resolution is 1366x768.

Comment: Try `sudo xrandr --addmode default 1920x1080`

Comment: The output: `xrandr: cannot find output "default"`

Comment: I will edit the question to include more details...

Comment: Try `xrandr --fb 1920x1080`

Comment: Did not work. Please clarify what does it do before posting the command.

Comment: Try using `xrandr` to list display information. On the second line it should say `(device name) connected primary ...`. Remember that device name. Run another command to calculate the CVT mode lines: `cvt 1920 1080` and note the output. It should have two lines. The second line should begin with `modeline`. Copy the whole output after `modeline` (which will begin with something like `"1920x1080_30.00"`). To add the new mode, run `sudo xrandr --newmode (the modeline output)`. (continued on next comment)

Comment: To add the new mode for your screen, run `sudo xrandr --addmode (device name from beginning) (the beginning of modeline, ex. "1920x1080_30.00"`). Make sure to add the quotation marks both here and in the newmode command. Go back into the display settings and add the mode for 1920×1080. Tell me if this worked.